# How do I pass a props correctly to update data in react using function components

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update a specific instance of a user via `setState()` function that updates it, but when I submit nothing happens.

The dummy data that I'm using:

```js
export let users = [
    {
        "id": "22",
        "firstName": "Joe",
        "lastName": "Schmoe",
        "totalExpense": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "22",
        "firstName": "Joe",
        "lastName": "Schmoe",
        "totalExpense": 0
    }
]
```

Parent Component:

```js
function App() {
  let [userData, setUserData] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    setUserData(data.users)
  },[])


  return (
    <div>
      <AppNav/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Users userData={userData}/>}/>
        <Route path="/:userid" element={<UserForm userData={userData} setUserData={setUserData}/>}/>
      
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Useredit component:

```js
export default function UserForm({updateUser, setUserData}){
    const { userid } = useParams()   

    // let [totalExpenses, setTotalExpense] = useState(0)

    let [user, setUser] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
    })


    function fillForm(e){
        const {name, value} = e.target
        setUser(prevUser => {
            return {
                ...prevUser,
                [name] : value
            }
        })
    }

    function updateUser(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        setUserData(prevData => prevData.map(currentUser => {
            if (currentUser.id === userid){
                return {
                    ...currentUser,
                    firstName: user.firstName,
                    lastName: user.lastName
                }
            }else{
                return currentUser
            }
        }))
    }

    return (
        <>
          <div className="form-container">
        <h1>Update User</h1>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={updateUser}>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="First Name"
                    className="form--input"
                    name="firstName"
                    onChange={fillForm}
                    value={user.firstName}
                    />
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Last Name"
                    className="form--input"
                    name="lastName"
                    onChange={fillForm}
                    value={user.lastName}
                    />
                <button 
                    className="form--submit"
                    >
                    Update
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </>
    )
}
```

I've tried moving the function into the app component but it wont let me pass event, so I can't prevent default page reload. Plus it does seem to work either.

Comment: Try setting the button type='submit' to submit the form

Answer (score 1):

When setUserData is received from the UserForm component
I think it is because updateUser is received instead of userData. Modify updateUser to userData.

```
export default function UserForm({userData, setUserData}){
const { userid } = useParams()
//.....
}
```